# Subset by year in a raster stack, save individual raster stacks, & then loop into biovars function in R

Tags: raster, r, for-loop

I have raster bricks of monthly max temperature, min temperature, and precipitation for various time periods (e.g., from 2090-2100, in this example).

```
> tmax
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 3875, 8017, 31065875, 132  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.04490319, 0.04490319  (x, y)
extent     : -180.0393, 179.9495, -90.04088, 83.95898  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 
source     : Z:/CHELSAcmip5ts_tasmax_ACCESS1-3_rcp85_2090-2100.nc 
names      : X2090.01.15, X2090.02.15, X2090.03.15, X2090.04.15, X2090.05.15, X2090.06.15, X2090.07.15, X2090.08.15, X2090.09.15, X2090.10.15, X2090.11.15, X2090.12.15, X2091.01.15, X2091.02.15, X2091.03.15, ... 
Date       : 2090-01-15, 2100-12-15 (min, max)
varname    : air_temperature
```

I need to (a) create individual raster stacks consisting of 12 layers for each year in the period. I know I can do the following to subset and save the individual rasters:

```
sub_ras <- subset(tmax,  grep("X2090", names(tmax)))  
writeRaster(sub_ras, file="tmax2090", format="GTiff")
```

But I am not sure how to loop this? I'll eventually need to do this for a raster brick of monthly data from 1970 to 2100.

Once I have my individual raster stacks for each year, I'll then need to read them in individually into the biovars function to create bioclim variables for each year. Shall I then use mapply to do this as follows:

```
pre = c("/path/pre2090.tif", "/path/pre2091.tif", ..., "/path/prec2100.tif")
tmax = c("/path/tmax2090.tif", "/path/tmax2091.tif", ..., "/path/tmax2100.tif")
tmin = c("/path/tmin2090.tif", "/path/tmin2091.tif", ..., "/path/tmin2100.tif")

output <- mapply(FUN = biovars, pre, tmin, tmax)
```

Will this give me a biovars raster for each year?

Or, does someone have a more elegant suggestion for this process?

Comment: Please use code formatted text rather than a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the loop part, the following code iterates between 90 and 100 writing a layer for each year; the layers will have bands for each month:

```
library(raster)
library(dismo)

for(i in 90:100){ 
sub_ras <- subset(tmax,  grep(sprintf("X2%03d", i), names(tmax)))  
writeRaster(sub_ras, file=sprintf("tmax2%03d.tif", i))
}
```

To get all 12 layers for each year we've written to file you may use `stack("tmax2090.tif")`.
And instead of writing each file name you may use:

```
tmax_names = list.files("path", "tmax", full.names = T)
```

Then you may use the `mapply` function as you intended.

The same objective may be reached if you directly calculate the `biovars` in the for loop, this way you may avoid duplicating the files, for instance:

```
for(i in 90:100){ 
sub_tmax <- subset(tmax,  grep(sprintf("X2%03d", i), names(tmax)))  
sub_tmin <- subset(tmin,  grep(sprintf("X2%03d", i), names(tmin)))
sub_prec <- subset(prec,  grep(sprintf("X2%03d", i), names(prec)))
bv_temp = biovars(sub_prec, sub_tmin, sub_tmax)  
writeRaster(bv_temp, file=sprintf("biovars2%03d.tif", i))
}
```

Furthermore, if you want to stack them together (all the 12*20):

```
bv = stack()
for(i in 90:100){ 
sub_tmax <- subset(tmax,  grep(sprintf("X2%03d", i), names(tmax)))  
sub_tmin <- subset(tmin,  grep(sprintf("X2%03d", i), names(tmin)))
sub_prec <- subset(prec,  grep(sprintf("X2%03d", i), names(prec)))
bv_temp = biovars(sub_prec, sub_tmin, sub_tmax)  
colnames(bv_temp) = paste0(sprintf("X2%03d_", i), colnames(bv_temp))
bv = stack(bv, bv_temp)
}
```